# Flex Tree node not getting selected properly

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

**Flex 4.1 SDK**

I'm using **mx:Tree** component to load a static xml data to bring it in the tree form. I'm having a HDivided box where my left side portion will have the tree and the right side major portion will be a border container with Flex IFrame component in it.

On creationComplete event, I'm assigning the dataprovider of the Tree component with the static xml data. The tree is loaded with the xml data. If I select any particular leaf node in the tree, the right side portion(i.e IFrame inside a Border Container) should be loaded with the html content corresponding to the selected node data. No issues in that.

The problem I have is after I load the flex module,

Step 1 :

Without selecting any of the top nodes, I'm selecting (clicking) the node E1 under E. The corresponding HTML content is loaded smoothly.

Step 2:

Then, If I select the D2 node under D branch, the selection of D2 is not happening and it is retaining with E1 itself. Obviously, the itemClick handler will have the selected item as E1 and the same E1 content is loaded again.

The selection is not changing to D2.

Rather, If I select any other node than D2, like D1, C1, C2 etc, the selection of the node changes and the corresponding node's HTML content is loaded properly.

Why the selection does not change ? Does the last node in the tree is having any issue ?

**test.xml**

```
    <root>

    <A label="A">
        <menu label="A1" />
        <menu label="A2" />
        <menu label="A3" />
        <menu label="A4" />
    </A>
    <B label="B">
        <menu label="B1" />
        <menu label="B2" />
        <menu label="B3" />
    </B>
    <C label="C">
        <menu label="C1" />
        <menu label="C2" />
        <menu label="C3" />
    </C>
    <D label="D">
        <menu label="D1" />
        <menu label="D2" />
    </D>
    <E label="E">
        <menu label="E1" />
    </E>

</root>
```

**FxTree.mxml (Application container)**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               width="100%" height="100%"
               creationComplete="onCreationComplete(event)">
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout/>
    </s:layout>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <fx:XML id="xmldata" source="/xml/test.xml"/>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.XMLListCollection;
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import mx.events.ListEvent;

            [Embed('/assets/icons/branch.png')]
            public  const  branchIcon:Class;

            [Embed('/assets/icons/nobranch.png')]
            public  const  nobranchIcon:Class;

            [Embed('/assets/icons/chart.png')]
            public  const  chartIcon:Class; 

            [Bindable]
            private var treeData:XMLListCollection;

            /**
             * Function for setting the node icons 
             * of 'systemdashboardTree'
             */
            private function setTreeIcon(item:Object):Class {
                var iconClass:Class;
                var classType:String = XML(item).attribute("icon");
                if(classType!="")
                    return this[classType];
                else
                    return null;
            }

            /**
             * Function called on 'creationComplete' event 
             * for feeding data to 'systemdashboardTree'
             */
            protected function onCreationComplete(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                treeData = new XMLListCollection(new XMLList(xmldata));
                fxTree.dataProvider = treeData;
            }

            /**
             * Function which handles the systemdashboardTree's
             * itemDoubleClick event
             */
            protected function onItemDoubleClick(event:ListEvent):void
            {
                var item:Object = Tree(event.currentTarget).selectedItem;
                if (fxTree.dataDescriptor.isBranch(item)) {
                    fxTree.expandItem(item, !fxTree.isItemOpen(item), true);
                }
            }

            /**
             * Function for loading the selected dashboard
             */
            private function loadDashboard(event:ListEvent):void {
                var item:Object = event.currentTarget.selectedItem;
                Alert.show(item.@label);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>



    <s:Panel height="100%"
             width="100%"
             title="FxTree"
             borderColor="#CCCCCC">
        <mx:HDividedBox height="100%" width="100%">
            <s:BorderContainer height="100%" width="20%" borderColor="#CCCCCC">

                <s:layout>
                    <s:VerticalLayout/>
                </s:layout>

                <mx:Tree id="fxTree" 
                         width="100%" height="100%" 
                         labelField="@label"
                         showRoot="false"
                         allowMultipleSelection="false"
                         doubleClickEnabled="true"
                         itemClick="loadDashboard(event)"                       
                         itemDoubleClick="onItemDoubleClick(event)"
                         borderSkin="{null}"/>
            </s:BorderContainer>

            <s:BorderContainer id="dashboardContainer" height="100%" width="80%" borderColor="#CCCCCC" />

        </mx:HDividedBox>
    </s:Panel>

</s:Application>
```

This is the actual code I used in my application.

TestModule.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Module xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" layout="absolute" width="100%" height="100%">
    <fx:Declarations>

        <fx:XML id="data" source="/xml/Test.xml"/>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.XMLListCollection;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            [Bindable]
            private var treeData:XMLListCollection;

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

        <mx:Tree id="trendsTree" 
                 width="50%" height="50%" 
                 labelField="@label"
                 dataProvider="{data}"
                 horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0"
                 showRoot="false"/>
</mx:Module>
```

Test.xml

```
 <root>

    <A label="A">
        <menu label="A1" />
        <menu label="A2" />
        <menu label="A3" />
        <menu label="A4" />
    </A>
    <B label="B">
        <menu label="B1" />
        <menu label="B2" />
        <menu label="B3" />
    </B>
    <C label="C">
        <menu label="C1" />
        <menu label="C2" />
        <menu label="C3" />
    </C>
    <D label="D">
        <menu label="D1" />
        <menu label="D2" />
    </D>
    <E label="E">
        <menu label="E1" />
    </E>

</root>
```

Comment: Your explanation is not clear. Can you link to the swf?

Comment: Your code seemed to work fine for me.

Comment: It works realy fine, what's the matter?

Comment: @Suni D. : Yes I agree. The code (which I tried as a sample) I have given here works fine though. But, same code which I'm using in my project is having the issue as what I said. To be more clear after many iterations, the immediate or the first child of any branch is selected properly. Only the last node in any branch could not be selected. ie. **case 1** : I'm selecting E1 node first and then I'm trying to select D2. this case fails.  **case 2** : I'm selecting E1 node first and then I'm trying to select C3. this case fails.

Comment: @Anton : **case 3** : I'm selecting E1 node first and then I'm trying to select C2. this case passes. I'm able to select the nodes like A1, A2, A3, B1 , B2, C1 bt not the last nodes in any branch after selecting the bottom node E1.                     I could not sort out what is the issue in this ? I removed all the event listeners like itemClick, itemDoubleClick etc of the tree. Now its a simple tree loaded with xml data on creationComplete event. May be immediately after setting the dataprovider property, Im accessing the tree, Im having this issue ? the children are not created properly ?

Comment: When I'm using the tree inside a mx:module, I'm having the issue. Any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Flex and have found [this](http://blogs.adobe.com/peterent/2006/10/28/tree_control_da/) and [this](http://blogs.adobe.com/peterent/2006/11/) article by Peter Ent to be clear and very informative on trees in flex. In the second link you want to read **Tree Drag and Drop Part 1** which is at the bottom of the blog, and **Tree Drag and Drop Part 2** which is in the middle of the blog. These answered all my questions about drag and drop. Good luck and happy coding!